# How can I access every Point Nodes with a Java method on Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I want to use lists to manage the Point Nodes, but there is a lot of them.

So does any method exist to access all the Point Nodes?

PS : Don't mind the mistakes, english isn't my native language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create ArrayList collections of type PointNode as below:
[image]

Then loop through all points in col_MyPoints as

```
for (PointNode currentPoint : col_MyPoints){
    do whatever;
}
```

Comment: obviously, you have to manually add them to the list yourself. If we are talking 100s of points, you might want to start creating them programmatically. Or you select them all in the canvas, right-click and then "create collection"

Comment: Your comment about adding 100s of points with the right click is exactly what I needed, thank's a lot !